# General sibling selector (tilda, ~) within :has() pseudoclass in JSoup doesn't work as expected

Tags: jsoup

I have a problem with results returned by method `select` from library JSoup when used on a selector that contains general sibling selector placed within `:has()` pseudoclass.
Let's say we have the following HTML code:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <p>
            paragraph1
        </p>
        <p>
            paragraph2
        </p>
        <p>
            paragraph3
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the example above selector: `p:has(~p)` should select each paragraph except the very last one, i.e. 'paragraph1', 'paragraph2'. Using this selector in JSoup `el.select("p:has(~p)")` results in an empty list. When tested in chromium-based browser inspector I get the expected results. On the other hand Firefox inspector seems to work like JSoup does.

My intension is to grab `strong` element from the last paragraph that contains `strong` element (from the last seven paragraphs of a list)
`p:not(:has(~p > strong)):nth-last-child(-n+7) strong`

It seems that tilde within a pseudoclass element is the thing that doesn't work here.

Comment: Just use `p ~ p {...}`, no need for `:has`